# Create archive for difference between tow tags with git

Tags: git, tags, archive, difference

I'd like to create archive, with only modified files, between tow tags with Git, it is possible ?

I suppose it start with :

```
git archive -o update.zip ...
```

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627). What's your goal here?

Comment: I use phing to deploy, and I create a tag before each deployment, then I'd like to have modified files between tow lasts tags

Comment: Git already includes a mechanism for efficiently sharing deltas between copies of your code: `git push` (or `git fetch` / `git pull`). Is there a reason you don't want to do that?

Comment: To create archive to send via scp on my server